Why are Packed Arrays limited to signed machine precision types?
Why are packed arrays limited to only a few types? Particularly, why are integer packed arrays limited to signed integers?
And is there a way to get the same efficiency you get with packed arrays in compiled functions but for arrays of fixed size unsigned integers (ex: UnsignedInteger64)?

If the length of an item is known, a list of items can be stored consecutively and access is by offset. For a new type with unknown length, this will not work. You could try to implement a new type with given length using ByteArray . Better still, you could try  a function in C or machine language and implement it as external function.

'why are integer packed arrays limited to signed integers' - I would say because there is no unsigned integer in WL, or 16- or 32-bit integers for that matter, just Integer.  You can use a NumericArray with these other types, but when you pass it to any other WL function you generally need to call Normal on it anyway.

So for normal noncompiled WL integer arrays, what happens when you get larger than a signed machine int? Does it unpack the array or do the array elements get promoted somehow?

And is there a way to do efficient computation over arrays of larger integers (with or without compilation)? I've tried to look into ways to hint WL that I want to do SIMD computation over arrays of integers within the range [0, 2^64-1] but I haven't been able to find any docs on how to do that.

(converting comments to answer)

why are integer packed arrays limited to signed integers

I would say because there is no unsigned integer in WL, or 16-bit or 32-bit integers for that matter, just Integer.  Part of what is great about packed arrays is that they work in the background and are mostly invisible to the user, unless they go looking for developer-designed functionality.

for normal noncompiled WL integer arrays, what happens when you get larger than a signed machine int? Does it unpack the array or do the array elements get promoted somehow?

Yes, and you can see here that the system will automatically and quietly convert from using 64-bit integers to some kind of bignum representation:
In[75]:= With[{n = 2^63 - 1},
 Developer`PackedArrayQ /@ {Range[n - 10, n], Range[n - 10, n + 10]}
 ]

Out[75]= {True, False}

If you want to work with large integers but make sure they are efficiently packed you can use NumericArray, which will give an error if the input can't be cast to the given type:
In[93]:= With[{n = 2^64 - 1},
 NumericArrayQ@NumericArray[#, "UnsignedInteger64"] & /@ {Range[
    n - 10, n], Range[n, n + 10]}
 ]

During evaluation of In[93]:= NumericArray::nconvsa: The argument {...} cannot be automatically converted to a NumericArray of type UnsignedInteger64. Try using one of the following conversion methods: "Round", "ClipAndCoerce" or "ClipAndRound".

Out[93]= {True, False}

Numeric arrays can be used on compiled code using the corresponding type specifier.
